# WordPress Ajax callback function from plugin - OOP

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, admin, hooks, oop

Using [PluginBoilerplate](https://github.com/omarabid/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) to write a plugin.
I need to make an ajax call.

I added to main `plugin.php` file, class to register scripts and handle ajax calls.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX' ) ) {

class PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX{
    public static $instance = null;
    public $nonce = '';
    public $name = 'ajaxexample';
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        null === self::$instance AND self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function __construct(){
        # Could as well be: wp_enqueue_scripts or login_enqueue_scripts
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scriptsEnqueue' ) );
        # Logged in users:
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'scriptsRegister' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scriptsLocalize' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'ajaxRegister' ) );


    }
    public function scriptsRegister( $page ){
        $file = 'page-1.js';
        wp_register_script(
            $this->name ,
            WPBP_URLPATH . '/app/files/js/' . $file ,
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
    public function scriptsEnqueue( $page ){

        wp_enqueue_script( $this->name );
    }

    public function ajaxRegister() {
        add_action( "wp_ajax_{$this->name}_action",  array($this, 'ajaxexample'), '1' );
    }

    public function scriptsLocalize( $page ){
        wp_localize_script( $this->name, "{$this->name}Object", array(
            'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'action'           => "{$this->name}_action"
        ) );
    }

   public function ajaxexample(){
        ob_clean();

        echo json_encode( array(
            'success' => true
        ) );
        wp_die();   
    }
}
}
```

the class being called after vendor/autoload.php is included.

**the main issue** is that although the script is successfully registered, enqueued and localized, the ajax callback function is not taking action.

ajax call is returning empty response: html page with same content as the one im in. `response.success` is undefended.

```
    ( function( $, plugin ) {
           $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#moreroles').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                /* Act on the event */
                var data = plugin;
                $.ajax({
                    url: plugin.ajax_url,
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend : function( d ) {
                        console.log( 'Before send', d );
                     }
                })
                .done( function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX done', textStatus, jqXHR, jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                } )
                .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX failed', jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), textStatus, errorThrown );
                } )
                .then( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX after finished', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
                } );

            });
    } );
} )( jQuery, ajaxexampleObject || {});
```

Comment: If you are getting a 0 response, it means either action is missing or doesn't match any hooked action. I don't think you are correctly passing the action in your JS.

Comment: the data object has 'action' inside of it equals to "ajaxexample_action". it suppose to direct ajaxexample function on the PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX class.

Comment: According to your localize call, `action` is a property of `ajaxexampleObject`.

Comment: @Milo take a look at my editing. i referred plugin variable as ajaxexampleObject.

Comment: A simple test to see if your function is correctly hooked is to manually visit `admin-ajax.php` URL in your browser and pass the action as a GET var, like `yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajaxexample_action`.

Comment: yes of curse, it's not properly hooked. i'm getting 0.
the question is why...
as i wrote - this class is being called from the initial function on my plugin class. all other hooks are working fine.

Answer (score -1):

**Wordpress can not load scripts after init hook.**

[PluginBoilerplate](https://github.com/omarabid/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) is missing the correct handling process for those kind of usage.
[This OOP WP Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.io/) do it much better, and provide loader classes for admin and client.

Comment: This is incorrect. Scripts can be registered and enqueued all the way up through the `wp_enqueue_styles` action (and even a little afterwards, actually). In a typical request, that's more that 17 high-profile actions after `init`, as listed by the [WordPress Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Comment: @bosco so is it just the `wp_ajax_{$this->name}_action`  for your understanding?